# Is it possible to set method level variable as class level variable?

Tags: java, variables

I want to set my method level variable as class level variable. Is it possible to set method level variable as class level variable in Java?i want to get method level variable value as class level variable how to get it?

```
class A {       
    void m(String s){
        String s1 = s;
     }
}
```

Comment: It is called a field or instance variable.

Comment: When you edit your question, do not delete the previous content, instead **add** the new info (otherwise the answer will be useless for future visitors)

Comment: I do not understand the new problem, the code looks like it's already working. Can you explain or give more details of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
class A {
String s;
void m(String s){
    this.s=s; //this keyword is used to ambiguity between local variable and class level variable
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess that you want (as a basic example)

```
class A {
    String s1; 

    void m(String s) {
        s1=s;
    }
}
```

Note that this is what you do with a setter function:

```
public class A {
    private String s1; 

    //Since the attribute is private, you need a function to access to the value
    public String getS1() {
        return this.s1;
    }

    public void setS1(String s) {
        this.s1 = s;
    }
}
```

And you can also pass the *dynamic* value in the class constructor:

```
public class A {
    private String s1; 

    public A(String s1) {
        this.s1 = s1;
    }

    //Since the attribute is private, you need a function to access to the value
    public String getS1() {
        return this.s1;
    }

    public void setS1(String s) {
        this.s1 = s;
    }
}
```

Comment: public String s1; 
 public B(String s)
 { 
      this.s1 = s;
      System.out.println(s1);   
    }  
 public void v()
 {
  System.out.print("value of s1 is"+this.s1);
 }

Comment: sorry @Luiggi Mendoza i can't access my local level vaiable

Comment: @KrishnaMoorthy since the attribute is private, you should use a getter to access to it from outside the class.

Comment: @KrishnaMoorthy that's not a local level variable, is an attribute. You can define a local level variable with the same name as the attribute (this is *shadowing*) but it will have a different value from the class attribute value. Please explain your problem by editing your question and adding the new problem.

Comment: i try to print s1 value in different method,how to print the dynamic value in different method

Answer (score 1):

If you asking about setting the **Instance variable** in that method here's how you do it.

```
String s;//instance var
 void m(String s)//s is dynamic value
 {
     this.s=s;
 }
```